# Using JS Link set field value OnPostRender

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, jslink, client-side-rendering

I want to set field values of different fields after OnPostRender using JS Link.

I am able to create the field and set value, but I want to set value only and for the little task I think creating the whole field is not a good idea.

Below is the required missing code

```
(function () { 

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  OnPreRender: function() { console.log('CSR OnPreRender'); },
  OnPostRender: [
   // set value in Title field
   // How to do this ?
  ]
});

})();
```

Below is the Working code which creates field and also sets value

```
(function () {


    var ctx = {};
    ctx.Templates = {};
    ctx.Templates.Fields = {
        'Title': {
            'NewForm': setTitle
        },
        'Body':{
            'NewForm': setBody
        },
         'Project':{
            'NewForm': setProject
        }
    };


    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);


})();


function setTitle(ctx) {
    var temp = 'Title 1'; //extract parameter from a query string    
    ctx.CurrentFieldValue =  temp ; //set field value   
    return SPFieldText_Edit(ctx);   
}  

function setBody(ctx) {
    var temp = 'body text lorel ipsum';    
    ctx.CurrentFieldValue =  temp ;   
    return SPFieldText_Edit(ctx);   
}

function setProject(ctx) {
    var temp = 'p2';    
    ctx.CurrentFieldValue =  temp ; //set lookup field value 
    return SPFieldChoice_Edit(ctx);

}
```

Comment: I do not understand the problem...

Comment: I want to set value of already being created filed suppose Task Name, but to set value of Task Name I do not know the code,but somehow I got the code to create the field using CSR
I hope you understand that creating a whole control is not a good ida just to set it's value

Comment: You do not like this: "return SPFieldText_Edit(ctx); "?

Comment: @codemirror in theory you are right, creating the whole control seems like overkill if you just want to set its value. But from a practical perspective, you have a way to do what you want that works, why not just go with what's working already?  As they say: [if it ain't broke, don't fix it.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_it_ain%27t_broke,_don%27t_fix_it)